# Linq запрос к базе данных для фильтрации используя переменные

Tags: c#, sql, запрос, linq, dynamic

Итак имеется база данных с ноутбуками.

[image: Диаграмма]

Я объединяю все таблицы, и в условии where хочу использовать переменные для фильтрации. При чем  переменные, которые не имеют значение (точнее имеют по умолчанию ="") не учитываются в результатах выборки.

```
context = new DataBaseContext();

var NotebookInfo =
    (from 
            note in context.Notebooks
        join
            scn in context.Screens
                on note.Screen.ScreenId equals scn.ScreenId
        join
            process in context.Processors
                    on note.cpu.CpuId equals process.CpuId
        join
            rammem in context.Rammem
                    on note.ram.IdRAM equals rammem.IdRAM
        join
            rommem in context.Rommem
                    on note.rom.IdROM equals rommem.IdROM
        join
            vid in context.videocards
                    on note.videocard.IdVideocard equals vid.IdVideocard
        where note.Maker.Contains(MAKER) && scn.Permission.Contains(PERMISSION)
        select new
        {
            note.ImagePath,
            note.Maker,
            note.OS,
            note.Price,
            scn.Matrix,
            scn.Permission,
            scn.Diogonal,
            NameCpu = process.Maker,
            process.Model,
            process.Mhz,
            process.TDP,
            process.Cores,
            rammem.TypeofRAM,
            rammem.AnoutGBRAM,
            rommem.TypeofROM,
            rommem.AnoutGBROM,
            NameVideo = vid.Maker,
            ModelVideo = vid.Model,
            vid.SizeMem
        }).ToList();
```

Итак, данный запрос работает и фильтрует данные *по разрешению экрана ноутбука* или *по производителю*, или  *разрешению экрана ноутбука и по производителю*.
 Т.е, если переменная MAKER="", то запрос отработает только с переменной PERMISSION.

А как, например, в этот же запрос в where добавить переменную PRISE, которая позволяла бы фильтровать ноутбуки с ценой меньше PRISE, если PRISE != ""?
(Естественно в любой момент строку можно конвертировать в число)
(Не охота писать хранимую процедуру)

Comment: select new
        {}.Orderby(условие сортировки).Tolist();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается следующим образом:

```
// ваш запрос без .ToList
var query =
    from note in context.Notebooks
    ...
    where ...
    select new
    {
        ...
    };

// Динамически добавляем условие
if (PRISE != "")
    query = query.Where(...);

// Здесь материализуем запрос
var notebookInfo = query.ToList();
```